# module 'QuantLib' has no attribute 'CallabilityPrice'

Tags: python, quantlib

I have pip installed newest `QuantLib` for python 1.23 for Windows.
`ql.Callability()` is available but `ql.CallabilityPrice` is not provided.
Is there any issue?

Comment: There is no `CallabilityPrice` listed in the documentation.  What makes you think there is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CallabilityPrice` was renamed to `BondPrice` in the underlying C++ library a couple of versions ago.  The Python module kept the old version for a while but eventually did the same.

Comment: Thank you. ql.BondPrice generates the correct results for callable bonds.